# inserting a blank row before inserting the correct one mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I am working on a angular5 / php backend project, and I am having an issue where I have a registration form, when the user registers it creates a blank row (empty strings values) in the user table followed by the correct row (colomn values).

The following is my form:

```
<form *ngIf="!isLogin" (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()" [formGroup]="registerForm">
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname" formControlName="fn">
                                <div class="throw_error" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.fn.invalid && registerForm.controls.fn.touched">
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.fn.errors?.required">This field is required</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.fn.errors?.minlength">This field must be at least 3 characters</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.fn.errors?.maxlength">This field must have at most 10 characters</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname" formControlName="ln">
                                <div class="throw_error" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.ln.invalid && registerForm.controls.ln.touched">
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.ln.errors?.required">This field is required</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.ln.errors?.minlength">This field must be at least 3 characters</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.ln.errors?.maxlength">This field must have at most 10 characters</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <input type="email" name="email2" id="email2" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" formControlName="email2">
                                <div class="throw_error" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email2.invalid && registerForm.controls.email2.touched">
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email2.errors?.required">This field is required</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email2.errors?.email && !registerForm.controls.email2.errors?.required">This email is invalid</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password2">
                                <div class="throw_error" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.password2.invalid && registerForm.controls.password2.touched">
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.password2.errors?.required">This field is required</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.password2.errors?.minlength">This field must be at least 6 characters</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.password2.errors?.maxlength">This field must have at most 15 characters</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirm-password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" formControlName="confPass">
                                <div class="throw_error" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.confPass.touched && registerForm.controls.confPass.errors?.MatchPassword">Passwords do not match</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid" 
                                                class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Submit">
                                        <span class="throw_error" id="success">{{resultReg}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

This is my typescript code for the registration function:

```
onRegisterSubmit() {
const regFormValue = this.registerForm.value;

this.http.post("http://localhost/ProjetErgonomie/RegUser.php", regFormValue)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.receivedData = data;
    if (this.receivedData.success) {
      this.resultReg = "User added successfully";
    } else {
      this.resultReg = this.receivedData.errors;
    }
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
```

And this is my RegUser.php page:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

require_once ('./DBConnect.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db ,$port);

$regUserData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$fn = $regUserData['fn'];
$ln = $regUserData['ln'];
$email = $regUserData['email2'];
$pass = $regUserData['password2'];
$confPass = $regUserData['confPass'];  

$errorsReg = "";
$dataReg=array();

if($fn === '' || $ln === '' || $email === '' || $pass === '' || $confPass === ''){
    $errorsReg = 'Please fill all fields';
    $dataReg['success'] = FALSE;
}

else{
    $checkUserQuery = "select * from user where Email = '".$email."'";
    $result = $conn->query($checkUserQuery);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        $errorsReg = 'User already exists';
        $dataReg['success'] = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, NewUser)
            VALUES ('".$fn."','".$ln."','".$email."','".md5($pass)."',1)";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $dataReg['success'] = TRUE;
    }
}
$dataReg['errors']=$errorsReg;
echo json_encode($dataReg);
```

can you please tell me why am I getting a blank row before having the correct row inserted?

Comment: Just before this line $sql = "INSERT INTO user (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, NewUser)
            VALUES ('".$fn."','".$ln."','".$email."','".md5($pass)."',1)"; add echo "I have been run"; does that then appear twice?

Comment: wow, I didn't know people are using PHP as "real" backends, without actually generating hypertext. is there a reason to it?

Comment: Please please please use parameter binding whenever you make SQL queries with user supplied data, Even in code samples posten on stack exchange. Purge the idea of constructing SQL by concatenating strings from your mind.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix yes it did appear twice.

Comment: @Phil I am sorry I didn't get your point, I am new into web development.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner you're right but my project isn't meant to be hosted online, it's a university project, but thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: @RoyNasr there was no point, just a question. Most people use something like Java/SpringBoot or Node.JS for the backend. I never used PHP before and thought it is only good for server-side HTML generation, not other backend jobs. I was just wondering why you use it.

Comment: @Phil I am using it because I haven't learned yet any other backend technology, but thank you for your clarification.

Comment: There could be 2 dependent problems. While the first flight connection to check to server OPTIONS at your back-end might writing the data in your database and your "===" checks might failing at that instance.